# Array filter by another array

Tags: javascript

i have an array:

```
arr 1 =
[
{id: 0, title: "A"},
{id: 1, title: "B"},
{id: 2, title: "C"},
]
```

And another array:

```
arr2 =
["0", "1"]
```

And from the arr1 I would like to choose object with `id == arr2[i]`

How to easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 =[
{id: 0, title: "A"},
{id: 1, title: "B"},
{id: 2, title: "C"},
]
const arr2 =["0", "1"]

console.log(arr1.filter(({ id }) => arr2.includes(String(id))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all matches to ids in the arr2 array

```js
const arr1 =[
{id: 0, title: "A"},
{id: 1, title: "B"},
{id: 2, title: "C"},
]
const arr2 =["0", "1"]

console.log(arr1.filter(el => arr2.indexOf(String(el.id)) != -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array's method `find()`

```js
const arr1 =[
{id: 0, title: "A"},
{id: 1, title: "B"},
{id: 2, title: "C"},
]
const arr2 =["0", "1"]

const obj = arr1.find(e => e.id == arr2[1]);

console.log(obj || 'Not found');
```